# Xamarin PCL и Wcf Service: безопасность канала

Tags: wcf, xamarin, безопасность

Добрый день. 
пишу Wcf Service и клиента на Xamarin.PCL(Android, iOS).
Необходимо обеспечить наибольшую безопасность передачи данных между клиентом и Wcf Service? 
Нужно шифровать и подписывать пакеты передаваемые на Wcf Service и обратно. Со стороны Wcf еще необходима аутентификация по User/Password.
Подскажите каким образом лучше это все дело организовать.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, Xamarin до сих пор не реализует возможности дуплексных и защищённых соединений. При попытке реализации выдавало ошибку Method not allowed.